# What does assigning empty brackets achieve in Visual FoxPro?

Tags: visual-foxpro

Simple question here. I have an old application that I'm tasked to converting to C#. I hate to ask what seems to be ridiculously simple, but I can't find an answer.

```
PROCEDURE Calc
PARAMETER apples,bananas

IF TYPE([bananas])#[C]
  bananas=[] && What is this right here? Empty string? Empty array? Dynamic?
ENDIF
RETURN
```

Comment: In VFP, single, double quotes and brackets are interchangeable. So it means an empty string. Brackets is also used for arrays (interchangeably with parenthesis). Don't let this inconsistency fool you. If it is a string then it means "quotes". If it is a numeric inside, then means array member (no indexer in VFP).

Comment: BTW, its behavior is not the same as quotes and double quotes, and not all VFP coders know that fact. I believe, who used it like that in your code, also didn't know that fact. To his luck in that code it wouldn't matter.

Comment: And actually, you don't need to bother what that means there. You could shorten that procedure as:  Procedure Calc(apples, bananas)
endproc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple. It is an assignment of an empty string to the variable (or all array elements, if an array). It is the same as

> bananas = ""

Comment: I should add that one of the reasons you might use [] or single quotes is to easily handle a string containing double quotes. Example:bananas=[test "double quotes"]. In your case though, it is strictly assigning a empty string to the variable.

Comment: As soon as I get through this translating, hopefully I'll never have to look back!